# How to determine the current locale of my extjs application?

Tags: extjs

In Extjs, I have created a package which is being used in an application. Is there any way to determine what is the locale that is set in the application from within the package, so I could update my strings. I am trying to avoid sending a request to identify the locale.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: by "what is the locale that is set in the application" do you mean that there is somewhere in your app where the the user specifies what the locale is? or are you trying to read the locale setting from the browser?

Comment: I went through the sencha docs and found that the locale could be set in the app.json file. Is there a way i can get to know that locale from inside the package?

Comment: Every answer I find that answers a question that I have about ExtJS is old and/or without answer. I hate this framework.